# What is the difference in instruction completion rate, instruction throughput, instructions per clock?

Tags: cpu, performance, computer-architecture, pipelining

From what I understand:

**ICR (Instruction Completion Rate)**: Is (# of instructions / time)

**Instruction Throughput**: Is usually an average of the number of instructions completed each clock cycle.

**IPC (Instructions Per Clock)**: Is how many instructions are being completing each clock cycle. (Maybe this is usually an average?)

I'm confused on these definitions, I'm definitely looking for clarification. They might even be wrong, I've been having a tough time finding clear definitions of them.

- How does the instruction completion rate affect overall performance of the processor?
- How is Instruction Throughput affected compared to IPC?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is a duplicate of [What is the difference in instruction completion rate, instruction throughput, instructions per clock?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40454219/instruction-completion-rate-vs-instruction-throughput-vs-instructions-per-cloc) created by you on StackOverflow.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it has been cross-posted to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40454219/instruction-completion-rate-vs-instruction-throughput-vs-instructions-per-cloc. Please read [Is cross-posting a question on multiple Stack Exchange sites permitted if the question is on-topic for each site?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/).

Comment: I didn't downvote it at all, I closed it for the reason I stated above. If you want to get the one on the other site closed or flag it to be migrated here (so I can merge its answer into this question) then this question can be reopened as it is then the "live" question. The meta question I linked tells you why we don't like cross-posting and what you should do.

Comment: Okay, I've voted to close to mitigate to here. Thank you for the help. I wasn't sure where the best place was to ask the question so I asked it here. The two sites get different readers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All terminology and detailed inter-relationship of processor inner workings are clarified in the fundamental textbook by [Hennessy and Patterson, Computer Architecture -- A Quantitative Approach](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.115.1881&rep=rep1&type=pdf).

In short, IPC and Instruction throughput are nearly same things depending on context, while the ICR will depend on amount of pipeline stalls due to cache misses, which forces the CPU simply wait, so no instructions are executed. IPC is a theoretical measure of the potential performance of a CPU, while the ICR is a measure of practical performance of a computing system on a particular workload.